# Изменение URL без перезапуска страницы

Tags: url, ajax, php

Добрый день.

Как можно сделать так, чтоб менялся URL, но не перезапускалась страница?
Например, на картах гугла перезапуска не происходит, данные подгружаются айксом, но при этом ещё и URL меняется.
Как такое сделать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

[Введение в HTML5 History API](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/)

> До появления HTML5 единственное, что мы не могли контролировать и управлять (без перезагрузки контента или хаков с location.hash) — это история одного таба. С появлением HTML5 history API все изменилось — теперь мы можем гулять по истории (раньше тоже могли), добавлять элементы в историю, реагировать на переходы по истории и другие полезности. В этой статье мы рассмотрим HTML5 History API и напишем простой пример, иллюстрирующий его возможности.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.hash = ' Пишите, что хотите';
```

Проверить работу, можно в консоли браузера.

Comment: А чего там добавляется #? Можно сделать, чтоб обычный запрос был и вслучае чего по ссылке можно было бы пройти и получить конкретный ответ (ну, как в картах гугла, например?

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, вам же уже ответил @kolpak. Правда, не так развёрнуто, но направление всё же дал правильное. Если хотите, то есть достаточно кроссбраузерный [плагин для работы с History API][1].

   [1]:https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API#%D0%A0%D0%A3%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%99